# wanted to change jcarousel skin but now div is completely missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcarousel

I copied the skin.css (.jcarousel-skin-tango) and replaced the class name (.jcarousel-skin-tango) with my new class name (.carouselskin). Afterwards I changed the filename of the css, uploaded it to the server and added

```
<link href="./skins/tango/myskin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In addition, I changed the class name in my file

```
<ul id="newcarousel" class="carouselskin">
```

Now the skin doesn't work. I looked in the html source code and saw that the most outer div was missing

```
<div class="carouselskin">
<div style="position: relative;" class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal">
...
```

What is wrong here? Is it because there are two jcarousel created?

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
      scroll: 1,
      wrap: "circular"
    });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#newcarousel').jcarousel({
    // Configuration goes here     
  }); 
});
```

Comment: why do you have two carrousels in the same script? they are both calling #newcarousel wich I'm guessing is the missing div. Doesn't it solve if you delete one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin creates the outer wrapper using the class name `jcarousel-skin-...` where ... is the name of a skin

Because the new class name you have added is not in the format `jcarousel-skin-...` the wrapper div is not being created.

Try using the classname `jcarousel-skin-carouselskin` on your `<ul>` and you should get the wrapper element once more.

You'll also need to update any `.carouselskin` selectors in your style sheet so that they target `.jcarousel-skin-carouselskin` not `.carouselskin`

Good luck!